# Common Tooltip style in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip

Can I make a tooltip style which can be applied to all tooltips for every control?

I tried this but I cant get the content (Tooltip text) in style, it is showing empty text in tooltip:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
                    <StackPanel Margin="7,1" >
                      <Border Background="#FFF7F7CC" CornerRadius="1" >
                            <TextBlock Margin="1" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For Using this style I have to put a seperate Tooltip tag in control, eg to apply tooltip to border,

```
<Border>
    <Border.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip ToolTip="This is tooltip text"  />
    </Border.ToolTip>
........
.........
</Border>
```

but is there any way where tooltipstyle applies to all control with tooltip mentioned in same tag.
eg.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Help" ToolTip="This is Tooltip" >
.....
.....
</Border>
```

let me know if any further details are required.
Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Your approach will work. But a small change is needed in the Control Template. Replace the TextBlock with ContentPresenter.

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
                    <StackPanel Margin="7,1" >
                        <Border Background="#FFF7F7CC" CornerRadius="1" >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Why should he do that? A `TextBlock` can also be used.

Comment: Yes TextBox/TextBlock can be used. But Content property should bound, not the ToolTip property.

Comment: @XAMLLover, Thanks its working. But I could not understand how putting contentpresenter instead of textblock make it working. Can you provide some understanding please ?

Comment: @Hardik : Tooltip is basically a ContentControl, so even though you used TextBlock, you should bind the Text property of TextBlock to Content property of ToolTip to make it work. But you targeted a wrong property.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/what-contentpresenter - Check this link. It will explain the need of using ContentPresenter in ControlTemplate.